# Ranking Scores in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

on the attached example I am trying to rank which sections of a test have been best/worst scored in..

Columns AQ:BJ show the % of each topic and I have managed to get it to dynamically ignore if a topic was not covered in a test.

Columns BK:CD should now rank these scores 1-20 but it is repeating rank places 'seemingly' at random... Ideally, I'd like this to ignore the blanks from AQ:BJ too (dynamically, so I can reproduce this for other tests), so I guess my ranking for this example would be 1-15 and 5 blank spaces.

Columns CE:CX would then take the headings of columns BK:CD so I have a workable bit of text in each cell in this range.

As you can see, its almost working but the rank bit has gone wrong somewhere!

Thanks

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nMhyX3RwjDFZgA2VObaiJnKL8qQZecUG0RSFQHFwVBU/edit#gid=384857421

Comment: Can you maybe add in the ideal expected output for one or two name students somewhere at BK:CD4 empty space?!

Comment: @rockinfreakshow done for DEMO BK10:CD10. I guess I can just use an iferror to get rid of the #N/A's in CE:CX. I'm hoping this formula will be able to automatically rank them so there are no duplicate numbers of there are several values of the same amount.

Answer (score 1):

Added formula here on the [copy tab](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nMhyX3RwjDFZgA2VObaiJnKL8qQZecUG0RSFQHFwVBU/edit#gid=1280286729&range=BK6) (`Column BK`). Please do test it out.

```
=index(let(Σ,column(AQ$1:BJ$1),
    Δ,sort({tocol(Σ),tocol(AQ6:BJ6)},2,0),
    Γ,filter(Δ,index(Δ,,2)<>""),
    xlookup(Σ,index(Γ,,1),sequence(counta(index(Γ,,1))),)))
```

[image]

Comment: whatever you have done, seems to work thank you! I'm not as well versed though.. how do I even access the formula to be able to transfer this to my real data...?

Comment: I cannot seem to 'view' named functions..?

Comment: Its like any other formula(s) you already have in the sheet to access and transfer. the symbols are just used as identifiers supported by the new [LET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535) function. no named functions used